# Generating a URL in ActionFilterAttribute based on a Controller and Action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, actionfilterattribute

I am using an ActionFilterAttribute in ASP.NET Core project. Apart of this method under some circumstances will generate a URL pointing to a controller/action which will be used by our React.js project.

For example we want to generate a URL like this http://localhost:1234/api/GetSomething/1

Currently i am using the ActionExecutingContext and  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.UrlHelper to generate a URL for action method

e.g. 
**var action = new UrlHelper(actionContext).Action("get", "Controller", new {id});**

This works fine when running the code normally, however it is causing a unit test to fail with an index out of range exception when it try to call the Action extension helper.

The test is creating an ActionExecutingContext and setting actionContext, I have tried creating a new RouteData and adding a couple of fake values, but it still fails. 
I presume that something is being set during startup.cs perhaps app.UseMvc()? That the test is not doing.

Does anyone have any suggestions both on how to properly generate a URL in ActionFilterAttribute ideally based on a controller and action or on how to get my test working?